# JSONMarshal: Is it possible to serialize/desrialize into/from 'plain' JSON (without metadata)?

Tags: json, web-services, delphi, serialization, delphi-xe7

I'm writing a DataSnap Rest Client (in Delphi) and I want it to provide 
data in json format to a lot of platforms (like C#, java, C++, Delphi). 
I'm using `TJsonMarshal` to serialize an object. I'm using something 
similar to this:

```
marshal := TJSONMarshal.Create(TJSONConverter.create);
jsonString := marshal.marshal(myObject).ToString;
```

But When I do it, the generated JSON is something like this:

```
{"type":"WJsonObj.TWPedido","id":1,"fields":
  {"Numero":1234,"Data":41606.7632623727,"VlrTotal":2543,
  "Produtos":
    [{"type":"WJsonObj.TWProdutoPedido","id":2,"fields":
      {"Codigo":"P001","Descr":"Computador","Qtde":1,"VrUnitario":1500}},

...

      {"type":"WJsonObj.TWProdutoPedido","id":4,"fields":
        {"Codigo":"P003","Descr":"Projetor","Qtde":1,"VrUnitario":745}}
    ]
  }
}
```

And I wanted plain JSON, without metadata (`'type'`, `'id'` and `'fields'`), so I 
wouldn't have extra json parsing in non-Delphi platforms. Is there a way 
to force the `TJsonMarshal` to serialize into "plain" JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `System.JSON` and `REST.JSON` instead of `Data.DBXJson` and `Data.DBXJSONReflect`

```
var
  foo, newfoo: TFoo;
  s: string;

  foo := TFoo.Create;
  s := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(foo);

  newfoo := TJson.JsonToObject<TFoo>(s);
```

Comment: Thanks. That was better, but I tried serializing an object with a list in it, and it added 'ownsObject' and 'arrayManager' as metadata...

Comment: Can this be used with TList?

Comment: Unfortunately Delphi JSON implementations have their quirks. You can use it with TList, but you will get extra fields... you can use TArray<...> instead. If you cannot handcraft your clasess to work with built in JSON support, you should look for 3rd party libraries.

Comment: [What would you recommend for a JSON library for Delphi?](https://plus.google.com/u/0/101151078020673275690/posts/TpTDUdUMDWs)

Comment: You can also find some current [JSON bugs listed in comments](https://plus.google.com/u/0/112273996831177908478/posts/Ti9Lm64UmxA)

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna change my implementation then. I'm thinking of writing the JSON manually now...